# pass an imageview in listview from activity 1 and recieve in activity 2 in an imageview

Tags: android, android-listview

this is my code in activity 1 :

```
   ImageView imgg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_flag);
    Bitmap  mImage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource    
(imgg.getResources),R.id.iv_flag);
    imgg.setImageBitmap(mImage1);

    String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_country)).getText()
            .toString();
    String pid2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_country_details)).getText()
            .toString();

    String pid3 =  ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_flag))
            .toString();


Intent i = new Intent(NewsPage.this,
            NewsPageDetails.class);
    // //i.setClass(Cafe.this,cafelistselected.class);
    i.putExtra("newspage", pid);
    i.putExtra("newspages", pid2);  
    i.putExtra("images", pid3);  // this is the string which contain the image 

    startActivity(i);
```

this is my code in activity 2  :

```
  public class NewsPageDetails extends Activity{
String hospitalpress;
String hospitalpress2;
String hospitalpress3;
TextView textmain;
TextView textmain2;
ImageView image;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newspagedetails);
    textmain=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textmainss);
    textmain2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textonee);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgview);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    hospitalpress = i.getExtras().getString("newspage");
    hospitalpress2 = i.getExtras().getString("newspages");
    int hodddddspitalpress3= i.getExtras().getInt("images", R.id.iv_flag);
    Bitmap  mImage1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // /////////////////////////////INSTRUCT//////////////////
    textmain.setText(hospitalpress);
    textmain2.setText(hospitalpress2);


    image.setImageResource(hodddddspitalpress3);
}
```

}

please let me now what exactly i write in the first activity and what i write in the second activity  to let the imageview (in activity 2)display the image that is in listview of (avtivity 1)

Hint : the images in listview is coming from mysql database not drawable .

Comment: Please clear your requirement. For ex: U need to pass data on click of listview or some thing else

Comment: yes on click (when the user click the listview (listview contains image view)it will go to activity 2 ,,in anctivity 2  recieve the imageview from the listview (1st activity) in imageview in(2nd activity)

Comment: @AndroidHacker Yes, i mean to pass data   ,this data are two things 1. text (which is done )  2.imageview (not done yetand this is my question ) hot pass it to another activity and recieve in imageview just it

Answer (score 0):

If U need to transfer data from one activity to another on click of list view then fallow undermentioned ( Hope U can do list view part by your own. Hoping U have created Adapter class as well )

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Service.this, SelectedService.class);

                            intent.putExtra("sp_name", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).sp_name);
                            intent.putExtra("image_url",
                                    m_ArrayList.get(arg2).your_image);
startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```